# Look at this margin bug of First element of Container! And Give proper reason for this

Tags: html, css, margin

Give some of your time to look on this fiddle. Here, Container1 and Container2 has background-color:#ccc, and h1, and .logo div has margins. Left and Right Margin are working fine. Why Margin-Top and bottom are not working correctly.

This is proposed to be it happens only when a container has first element with margin. Do you know why this happens? Answer with suitable reason.

http://jsfiddle.net/daljir/M4X7e/5/

Comment: I honestly can't explain why, but if you add `float: left; width: 100%;` to `containter and containter2` it works

Comment: Vertical margins collapse under certain circumstances, horizontals don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to margin collapsing effect which means that top/bottom margins collapses. This is also reason for elements not expanding inside.

#### More explanation here:

See [w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins),
and [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin_collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin_collapsing),
and [colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)

#### Fixing it:

There is different ways to fix collapsing, you could either set containers to be `float: left|right` (< or `position: absolute`, set `border: solid 1px` (*also try `border-top: solid 1px;` for better understanding it*) or set `min-height: height-with-margins` to prevent collaping.

#### Good thing to remember is that:

> When margin collapsing happens, the margin area is not clearly defined since margins are shared between boxes.
>
> Margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse.

Comment: If margin dimensions is not clearly defined (_which happens when margins collapse_) in elements inside container then we could not reliably calculate height of container element.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Actually, I was know the fixes. Just Wondering why this behave like that. You provide some written documentation for this to make this clear.